# TypeError при изменении списка оператором += внутри кортежа

Tags: python

Известно, что оператор `+=` для списков примерно эквивалентен методу `extend` в том смысле, что при его использовании не создаётся копия списка, а расширяется текущий.

В связи с этим возникает вопрос: почему следующая конструкция бросает исключение `TypeError`:

```
t = ([1], )  # кортеж из одного элемента, являющегося списком
try:
    t[0] += [2]
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)             # 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
print(t)                 # ([1, 2],) -- и сам список изменился!
```

Ведь мы не изменяем ссылки, сохранённые в кортеже и следующий код работает без проблем:

```
t = ([1], )
t[0].extend([2])
print(t)           # ([1, 2],)
```

Почему такое поведение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что операция `+=` всё же содержит в себе присваивание, хоть и выполняет изменение "на месте". Оператор `+=` реализуется через метод `__iadd__`, и код

```
t[0] += [2]
```

[эквивалентен следующей записи](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works):

```
res = t[0].__iadd__([1])
t[0] = res          # TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Хоть ссылка на самом деле и не меняется:

```
print(res is t[0])  # True
```

но присваивание есть, и это мешает выполниться подобному оператору без ошибок.

Способ с использованием метода, очевидно, такой проблемы иметь не может.

---

Можно удостовериться, что присваивание действительно есть. Для этого рассмотрим более простой случай:

```
a = [1]
a += [2]
```

Посмотрим, какой код генерируется в Python 3 для выполнения второй строки (операции могут отличаться, но суть будет примерно та же):

```
import dis
dis.dis('a += [2]')
                                             Расшифровка действия со стеком
  1           0 LOAD_NAME          0 (a)     push [1] (переменная "a")
              3 LOAD_CONST         0 (2)     push 2 
              6 BUILD_LIST         1         pop (2), push [2]
              9 INPLACE_ADD                  pop ([2]), pop ([1]), push [1, 2]
             10 STORE_NAME         0 (a)     pop ([1, 2] -> a)
                ...
```

Именно попытка выполнить операцию [`STORE_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME) (более точно, [`STORE_SUBSCR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_SUBSCR), для кортежа) вызывает ошибку в случае, описанном в вопросе. Важно понимать, что операция [`INPLACE_ADD`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-INPLACE_ADD) выполняет добавление элементов "на месте", т.е. на стеке в итоге окажется тот же объект.