# Почему в о одном случае возникает ошибка, а в другом нет? (python)

Tags: python

```
>>> a = ([],)
>>> a[0].append('pochemy')
>>> a[0] += 'tak'
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> a
(['pochemy', 't', 'a', 'k'],)
```

Почему во втором случае выдается ошибка? Ведь `+=`, в данном случае, изменяет сам объект, а не создает новый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что код:

```
a[0] += 'tak'
```

эквивалентен:

```
x = a[0]
x = x.__iadd__('tak')
a[0] = x
```

Вторая строчка нормально выполняется, изменяя список, но на третьей вылетает исключение, поскольку мы пытаемся изменить кортеж.

**Update:** вот хорошее подробное объяснение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482925/178077

Answer (score 1):

`x += y` это короткая форма `x = x + y`.

Как говорится в ошибке, кортежи не поддерживают присваивания элементов, по этому нельзя написать

```
x = (1,2)
x[0] = 3
```

Точно также нельзя написать

```
x[0] = x[0] + 1
# или
x[0] += 1
```

То же относится к любым другим типам элементов, в т.ч. и к элементам-спискам.

Comment: x += y  отличается от x = x + y  например a =[]; a +=[1] изменит список, а

Comment: x += y  отличается от x = x + y  например x =[ ]; x +=[1] изменит список, а x = x + [ 1] создаст новый список и назовет его х. В том и вопрос,почему моя программа хочет и меняет  объект (изменяемый объект [ ]),а на нее при этом возводят хулу?